# GetUniquePackageLabels doesn't use CartonId from _POST_FBA_INBOUND_CARTON_CONTENTS_

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-fba

I am using Amazon's MWS Feeds API to submit carton data using the **SubmitFeed** call for **_POST_FBA_INBOUND_CARTON_CONTENTS_**. There are no errors or warnings and all subsequent calls in my InboundShipment to Amazon work just fine. I can even get the labels using the **GetUniquePackageLabels** call, where I also send the same CartonIds in. It works just like it should except it uses for CartonId integers starting at 1, even though I provide a CartonId like 10053017. It should be on the shipping label, but instead I see under the barcode text like FBA140CDHXKXU000001, which is the ShipmentId followed by a a single character like 'U' then followed by a 6-digit CartonId (000001). Is it possible to get the CartonIds to come back in the label? The docs suggest it should work that way, but the only FBA images I've discovered have the 00001 type pattern.

Comment: I'm having trouble calling `GetUniquePackageLabels` with my generated carton IDs. I'm sending as ids 1, 2, 3, 4, etc, but when I call `GetUniquePackageLabels` with those carton ids, I get an error saying "Package Identifier/s provided are not valid <SHIPMENT ID>". If you could show me an example of your feed request to figure if I'm doing something wrong that'd be amazing :)

Comment: I do have the same question. As I am passing the exact CartonId which I submitted using Feed API. If anyone can answer this it will be a big help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon retains your submitted CartonId(s) but does not use them in the labels. All cartons are numbered starting 1 and the format is U.

For example, a shipment (ShipmentID = FBA13H23WS7C) of 2 cartons would generate labels with this text:

FBA13H23WS7CU0000001

FBA13H23WS7CU0000002

When you request unique labels, you do have to pass your CartonId, otherwise it fails.

Comment: Hi, @mike-stephenson can you please help with my above comment?