# Amazon Seller Central - SP-API - GET Labels for shipment

Tags: python, amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

I have no previous experience with Amazon MWS so maybe I'm not understanding the whole process flow. Now I'm trying to get labels for shipments I manually created over the Seller Central UI.
Shipments I created are successfully fetched (Operation: getShipments) and now I have issue when getting the labels.

Here is my error response from API:

```
{'errors': [{'code': 'InvalidInput',
   'message': 'Provided SellerCartonIds are not valid: [[FBAxxxxxxxxxU000001]] for Shipment: [FBAxxxxxxxxx]',
   'details': ''}]}
```

If I print labels from UI `FBAxxxxxxxxxU000001` label is printed in pdf - also found out about naming [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249677/getuniquepackagelabels-doesnt-use-cartonid-from-post-fba-inbound-carton-conten).

In general, I don't know where to find parameter of package labels `PackageLabelsToPrint` from [GetLabelsDocs](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/fulfillment-inbound-api/fulfillmentInboundV0.md#getlabels), also I'm not sure if this parameter is same as `cartonIdList` parameter?

Here is response if you don't provide `PackageLabelsToPrint` query param in request:

```
{'errors': [{'code': 'InvalidInput',
   'message': "1 validation error detected: Value null at 'cartonIdList' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null",
   'details': ''}]}
```

I spent a bit of time on this already and it gets a bit annoying.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need **PackageLabelsToPrint** it is your **cartonIdList**

[I used PostMan and here is my response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAm7j.png)

[And I got this PDF file link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzhrM.png)